# How to map this json to a custom class in java

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

Let's assume I have the following json

```
[
    {
        "00080005":{
            "vr":"CS",
            "Value":[
                "ISO_IR 100"
            ]
        },
        "00080054":{
            "vr":"AE",
            "Value":[
                "DCM4CHEE"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

How to create a custom class to map this in java?
I tried this class shape

```
public class custom1 {
    private Map<String, cusomt2> id;
}
```

and `cusomt2` shape is

```
public class cusomt2 {
    private Object vr;
    private Object[] Value;
}
```

and used Jackson mapper to map

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<custom1> test = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(responseStream, custom1[].class));
```

It's as expected, gives me an error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "00080005"
```

I want "0008005" as the field value not the field key, these values are dynamically changes according to the API, so how to map this json, is there any direct way other the last option op custom deserialize?

Comment: What do you think `mapper.readValue(responseStream, custom2[].class)` does? (Specifically the `custom2[]`.) Why do you assign the result of that (wrapped in a list) to a `List<custom1>`?

Comment: Unrelated: [java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Comment: I edit it, It should be custom1[] not custom2[], but this is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is the problem, actually there was 2 problems, @Alex Rudenko solved one, the other problem is that API returns `Value` as a capital letter, not `value`, actually I specify it as `Value` correctly in class, but the problem is that it's a private property, and it's getter named `getValue`, this confuses jackson when mapping, it considers `getValue` as a getter of `value` field not `Value`

- First solution(Recommended) was to set `@JsonProperty("Value")` annotation on the `Value` property in class.

So the class now looks like this

```
public class custom1 {

    private String vr;
    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private String[] Value;

    //getter & setters
}
```

- second solution is to make `Value` as public, to avoid using it's getter.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that there's no `id` field causing deserialization failure.

However, the input JSON represents a list/array of maps `Map<String, Pojo>`, where `Pojo` should be defined as:

```java
@Data
class Pojo {
    String vr;
    String[] value;
}
```

Then the JSON should be deserialized using `TypeReference`:

```java
String json = ...; // long json string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Pojo>> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {});
```